# Animation when iPhone app first loads query

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, animation

I need some expertise regarding an iPhone animation.  I have hired a company to develop an app for me and when the app is loaded for the first time, a short animation will play.  What I need to know is, if you have an animation play (quicktime movie) when your app first loads, is it possible to NOT have a black screen at any point in between the splash image that is first displayed and when the animation commences? Currently the splash image is a png of the first frame of the animation, so you see this first but then the screen goes black and then the animation starts.  Is it possible to have this png image displayed the whole time so that the screen doesn't go to black just before the animation commences?

The company is telling me it's not possible but I think this might be because they underquoted the project and now have to pay their developers more to make any further changes and they don't want to have to do this.  So if it is possible, can some one please reply with specific instructions as to how it can be done that I can go back to them with.

Many thanks!

Comment: You could test your theory by paying them more and seeing if the problem gets fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a QuickTime or other type of video.. Then yes the app wil show black screen while loading the video... A solution is to make the png of animation.. and then animating the images..  User won't be able to interact.. But no black screen.

Comment: Thanks! I have also just been told it is possible to have the png image as a holding image in the apps "real window" so that it will display while the quicktime video loads, is this true?  Also will a png sequence for the animation affect the size and speed of the app compared to a quicktime video?